# Trouble with Remuxing Video Files in C# using ffmpeg

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, mp4, video-processing

I am trying to remux MP4 video files in C# using FFmpeg to change their container format without re-encoding the video and audio streams.

However, my current implementation doesn't seem to be working, and I'm encountering issues. Here's the code I've been using:

```
using System.IO;

private void B()
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        while (File.Exists($"{Path.GetDirectoryName(file)}\\{i}.mp4"))
        {
            i++;
        }

        string outputDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
        string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(outputDirectory, $"{i}.mp4");

        // Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
        Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory);

        using (Process process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-i \"{file}\" -c:v copy -c:a copy \"{outputFilePath}\"";
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            MessageBox.Show("done");
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
when I run the code, nothing happens, and the video files are not remuxed as expected. The `MessageBox.Show("done");` line executes without any issues.

Additionally, I've heard that FFmpeg may not create the output file if the specified directory doesn't exist, so I want to know if there's a way to handle this properly within the code.

I've made sure that FFmpeg is installed correctly and the input file paths are accurate.

Could someone please review my code and point out any potential issues or suggest a correct approach to remuxing MP4 video files using FFmpeg in C#?

Comment: Demuxing streams and re-muxing them might not always work directly. The LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK has filters to convert between formats without re-compressing the data. See the [H264](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/multimedia/filters/lead-h264-transcoder.html), [H265](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/multimedia/filters/lead-h265-transcoder.html) and [AAC](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/multimedia/filters/lead-aac-transcoder.html) Trancoders. (Disclosure: I work for the SDK's vendor). If you'd like to try the SDK and its filters, there's a free evaluation [here](https://leadtools.com/downloads).